# Can I enter Poland from the USA using a oneway ticket?

Tags: usa, immigration, students, study, poland

So my situation is a little bit odd. Bear with me. I am 19 years old. I recently graduated high school here in the U.S. And I got accepted to Lazarski University in Poland. I have proof of acceptance, the payment, etc. But I don't have a visa.

I tried to apply for a student visa and was refused because I am a citizen "by blood" but not "by documentation."

I'm in the process of getting my Polish citizenship. About 2 months ago we went to a guy who does these sort of things for us, so we won't have to deal with document translations, all the paper work etc. He said it would take 2-3 months for me to get my PESEL number (or whatever it's called) and my Polish passport, officially making me a Polish citizen.

Unfortunately since I'll be flying out to Poland August 24th, I don't know if we will make it in time for me to get my Polish passport, thus making us continue the processes in Poland. So my question is will I have a problem with Polish immigration?

I could explain my whole situation to them but I don't know if they care or believe me. I've been reading different sites where some people were stopped at customs for having a one way ticket and some people were not.

Comment: While the other question still exists, there is a lot of discussion at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51781/can-i-travel-from-usa-to-poland-with-a-one-way-ticket which might be helpful for answerers. Michal: Perhaps you could add some of that info into the question.

Comment: Actually thats also my question, but I posted on here because my question was put "on hold" or something like that, and I was recommended that I should post on this forum.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's also your question. But there was a lot of clarification discussion added in the comments to that other question, which would be helpful to incorporate into your question here, so people here don't have to go through all the clarification again.

Comment: I don't understand why you wouldn't get a student visa to use until you get your Polish citizenship?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to simply buy a throwaway ticket out of Poland, e.g. a 20 euro Ryanair flight to the UK. You will have a peace of mind and something to show to immigration should they ask.